# firebase-collection polymer component not working when location URLs do not have "user"

Tags: firebase, polymer, polymer-1.0, firebase-polymer

I am having a problem with using Polymer's firebase-collection component. After following the [todo-app](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/polymer-firebase/index.html) example, I am able to access data from specific users, however I would like to do more advanced things such as denormalizing the data to have more flattened JSON data that many users can access globally see [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html) for firebase guidelines. My firebase data is set up in the following way:

```
{
    "users":{
        "uid1":{...}
    }, 

    "sharedDoc":{
        "section 1":{
             "0" : {"title": "Blah0"},
             "1" : {"title": "Blah1"}
             .
             .
             .
    }, 

}
```

after authentication, polymer's firebase-collection works fine with this URL location:

```
<firebase-collection location="https://(url-stuff)/(url-stuff).firebaseio.com/users/uid1"
                     data="{{userStuff}}"
                     >
</firebase-collection>
```

and within the scope of my element, this.userStuff is a variable that has everything in the uid1 branch

however, when I use this the URL to access non-user information like below:

```
<firebase-collection location="https://(url-stuff)/(url-stuff).firebaseio.com/sharedDoc"
                     data="{{sharedDoc}}"
                     >
</firebase-collection>
```

this.sharedDoc is empty.

Even after populating sharedDoc beforehand with "dummy" data, sharedDoc becomes empty afterward.

Does anyone have any resources that they can recommend to figure out how  I can fix this code so that the sharedDoc URL location returns the associated JSON from firebase (as above)?

Comment: Update! for some reason using firebase-document works, I am not sure why...

Comment: It looks like "sharedDoc" doesn't have a collection, rather "section 1" does. Try using that as your location.

Comment: @sfeast I think the problem may be coming from a lac of understanding with the definition of a "collection." Would you mind expanding on what makes  "section 1" a collection? (I suspect it has something to do with it being similar to an array)

Comment: Right - firebase-collection expects the data to be in an array like structure & firebase-document will just take whatever is at the firebase location you give it. It's not actually clear here what you have under "sharedDoc" in firebase so re-reading my comment I could have been incorrect depending on the structure under sharedDoc.